# How to pass a variable(string) from a running server script to another python file?

Tags: python, sockets, variables, import, tcp

I have a client python and a server python and the commands which work perfectly. Now I want to build the interface which needs a variable(string) from the server file and I encountered a problem.

**my client.py file**

```
import socket

s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((socket.gethostname(),1234))

s.send(bytes("command1","utf-8"))
```

**my server.py file:**

```
import socket

while (1):
    s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind((socket.gethostname(),1234))
    s.listen(5)
    clientsocket, address=s.accept()
    msg=clientsocket.recv(1024)
    message=msg.decode("utf-8") # I need to pass this to the other file
    print(message)
```

**the file in which I need to import the message string from the server.py file:**

```
    from tkinter import *
    from server import message


    def function():
        #do some stuff


    Menu_Win = Tk()

    photo = PhotoImage(file=r"path_to_local_file.png")

    Background_Main = Canvas(Menu_Win, width=1980, height=1080, bg="white")
    Background_Main.pack()

    Background_Main.create_image(0,80, image=photo, anchor='nw')

    if message=="command1": #this would be the variable from the server file
        function()


    Menu_Win.mainloop()


I tried to use **from server import message** but it gives me this error **OSError: [WinError 10048] Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted** and I found out that it gives me this error only when I am continuously running the server.py file and I thinking that the second files when imports, it imports the socket too.

UPDATE1: deleted


UPDATE2: deleted 

UPDATE3:

I have found myself a solution, by using threading library and running the echoing server on a thread and the rest of the code (GUI) on another.

import socket
from tkinter import*
import threading

message="dummy variable"

def test_button():
    print(message)

root=Tk()
Canvas(root, width=300, height=100).pack()
Button(root,text=("Server"), command=test_button).pack()

def get_command():
    while 1:
        global message
        s=socket.socket()
        s.bind((socket.gethostname(),1234))
        s.listen(5)
        clientsocket, address=s.accept()
        msg=clientsocket.recv(1024)
        message=msg.decode("utf-8")

t = threading.Thread(target=get_command)
t.start()

def my_mainloop(): #to actually see if the command is updated in real time
    print(message)
    root.after(1000, my_mainloop)    

root.after(1000, my_mainloop)

root.mainloop()
```

Thank you for all the support :)

Answer (score 0):

You could define a function in `server.py`:

```
import socket

s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((socket.gethostname(),1234))
s.listen(5)
clientsocket, address=s.accept()

def get_string():
    msg=clientsocket.recv(1024)
    message=msg.decode("utf-8") # I need to pass this to the other file
    return message
```

And then in your other program, import `server` and call the function `server.get_string()`:

```
from tkinter import *
import server


def function():
    #do some stuff


Menu_Win = Tk()

photo = PhotoImage(file=r"path_to_local_file.png")

Background_Main = Canvas(Menu_Win, width=1980, height=1080, bg="white")
Background_Main.pack()

Background_Main.create_image(0,80, image=photo, anchor='nw')

message = server.get_string()

if message=="abc": #this would be the variable from the server file
    function()


Menu_Win.mainloop()
```

Ps you are getting the error due to the fact that you are not shutting down the server after starting it, then you are trying to start the server again onto of the already existing server.

Comment: For the client(GUI) to work, the server.py file needs to run continuously otherwise I cannot send commands from the Interface.

Comment: In the example i provided, the server is started once and that code is not called again. Therefore the server will stay running without it starting again.

Comment: So when you import `server` the server is started, and then everytime you call `get_string` that function in the `server.py` file is run.

Comment: I tried and it works, BUT the interface won't start until I use the client command, AND the server is shutting down so I cannot send the second command.

Comment: What interface? The GUI one?

Comment: I updated my original post. I made an InfoPannel ni Raspi for my office. Basically when I call someone from the 1st monitor and information needs to appear on the second monitor but for a simple understanding in helping me I simplified the process.
I have in total 32 command which the server needs to check continuously and it works. Now I need to build an interface and those commands will show something on the screen.

Comment: You should put the receiving and if statments in a loop:

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    message = server.get_string()

    if message=="comand1":
        function1()

    if message=="comand2":
        function2()
```

And instead of using `Main_Win.mainloop()` you should place `Main_Win.update()` before the while loop:

```
Main_Win.update()

while True:
    message = server.get_string()

    if message=="comand1":
        function1()

    if message=="comand2":
        function2()
    Main_Win.update()
```

Comment: It almost work man. The GUI is starting, all the command are taken...but the GUI is frozen from the start. If I delete the while True, the GUI works fine...
Updated my original post. Can you bare a little more with me? Thanks

Comment: Is the GUI supposed to change according to the functions?

Comment: If so then dont forget to call `Main_Win.update()` from within the function after any of the widgets are changed

Comment: Or a the end of the while loop, check my updated answer.

Comment: It sill doesn't wok and I found out that if I delete ONLY the line message = server.get_string(), it works... I think now the problem is the server.py. The program freezes because there is no incoming string variable from the server.

Comment: It freezes because the server is waiting for the client to send something, check wether the client is sending more commands

Comment: I really do not know what to do. I can't believe that I got stuck at the end...
I though that using "from server import message" would work...that's why I didn't even think to study the problem more deeply.... I still can't believe that is that hard to pass a variable from a running script... maybe subprocceses, modules...idk :((

Comment: I have found myself a solution, by using threading library and running the echoing server on a thread and the rest of the code (GUI) on another. I updated my original code. Thank you for your time. See you around :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm really fond of [this](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html) library. The link comes with a full example which I think applies almost directly to your code.

The downside is that you hare to use an other port for this kind of communication to work or add the option reuse_address to the socket you currently use.